# ¿Por qué me dice "segmentation fault"?

Tags: c

**Cuando le doy el valor de un millón de datos, se detiene el programa, añadiendo la frase ,segmentación fallo, por favor, alguien me puede explicar. Gracias.**

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
int main()
{
    int n=1000000; /* aqui cuando le doy el valor de un millón falla el programa */

    int array_a[n];
    int array_b[n];
    int array_c[n];

    srand(time(NULL));

    /*sumamos los vectores unidimensionales
    asignamos valores random*/

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
       array_a[i]=rand()%250;
       array_b[i]=rand()%100;
    }

    /*suma final*/
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        array_c[i]=array_a[i]+array_b[i];
    }


    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("%d \t",array_c[i]);
    }


    return 0;

}
```

**Cuando le doy el valor de un millón de datos, se detiene el programa, añadiendo la frase ,segmentación fallo, por favor, alguien me puede explicar. Gracias.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suponiendo que en tu máquina, los enteros sean de 32 bits, estás pidiendo 96 millones de bits, que son unos 12Mb.

Dado que lo estás pidiendo en memoria automática, estos 12Mb irán a parar a la pila, la cuál normalmente no llega a esas cantidades. Tendrás que usar memoria dinámica:

```
int *array_a = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
int *array_b = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
int *array_c = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);

// ...

free(array_a);
free(array_b);
free(array_c);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo

Answer (score 0):

**Segmentation Fault** no quiere decir "Segmentación de Fallo" sino ["Violación de Acceso"](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violaci%C3%B3n_de_acceso) y tiene que ver con que estás asignando memoria a la cual no tienes acceso, ya sea porque está dañada o no tienes permisos para modificar o eliminar.

En este caso, es porque estás asignando espacios de memoria: 3 arreglos de 1M de enteros, lo cual excede lo permitido por C y tu configuración de hardware. Para poder tener arreglos de tamaño tan grande, intenta dar una revisa al concepto de [memoria dinámica](https://es.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programaci%C3%B3n_en_C/Manejo_din%C3%A1mico_de_memoria#Memoria_din%C3%A1mica).

Comment: En este caso, el *segmentation fault* viene dado porque supera el tamaño máximo de la pila.

Comment: Exactamente !!!

Comment: @carlosabcs muchas gracias revise ....es decir que tengo que estar en la heap...la memoria dinámica...luego bueno...asignar el tamaño que quiero.

Comment: Es que bueno me acostumbre a C++ y no sabía bien bueno también olvide el concepto de heap. Gracias igual.

Comment: Exacto @LuisGonzalesUsca. Si mi respuesta resolvió tu duda, no olvides marcar esta pregunta como resuelta :)